# Do adept enhanced physical attribute modify karma cost?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

For the enhanced attributes, do they modify the karma cost for increasing the physical attributes? (thus if you have strength 3 and have +2 for physical attributes: strength  do you then increase with karma as if you had strength 3 or strength 5?)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: No. Skills that increase attributes when activated/installed are considered as **Augmentation Bonuses** whereas that base number of the attribute is considered to be the **Natural Rating**.

Now, book quotes. (All emphasis mine)

First, let's talk about **Augmentation Bonuses**.

> First, when purchasing augmentations such as cyberware and bioware, **each attribute rating (Mental and Physical) can only receive an augmentation bonus of up to +4. If the attribute being raised has not reached its natural maximum limit, the attribute can be raised naturally with Karma;** but at no point can augmentations exceed the +4 bonus cap. *(Pg. 94 RAW)*

As outlined about, attributes have a natural rating (and maximum limit), and a maximum augmentation rating. This means that **anything that increases your attributes artificially does not count toward your natural attribute level**. You also have to note augmentation bonuses:

> Augmentations need to be noted on the character sheet. The rating should be added to the natural attribute rating and the total written in parentheses next to the natural attribute rating to indicate the permanent augmented rating. For example, a character with a natural Strength rating of 4 and muscle augmentation 2 bioware should record their attribute as follows: **Strength 4 (6)**. *(Pg. 95 RAW)*

And here:

> **Both non-augmented and augmented attributes** should be added together and listed the same as attributes, with the non-augmented number first followed by the augmented number in parentheses. *(Pg. 100 RAW)*

Now, some examples of where this augmentation is noted.

> **Attributes boosted by cyberware or bioware do not affect the calculation for things such as points for Knowledge skills or Contacts**. However, other in-game mechanics such as Initiative and Inherent Limits are modified by these augmentations, which means these bonuses need to be factored in during Step Eight: Final Numbers (p. 100). *(Pg. 95 RAW)*

This tells us that, at least for 'ware, their bonuses don't affect the **Rating** calculations, just the **Augmented** amount. While this example isn't an Attribute, they function relatively the same. Furthermore, they go on to explain how it should be noted:

Specifically for Adepts, we have:

> **This augments your attribute**, so your Physical limit may also increase with the new Attribute rating. This power **allows you to exceed your natural Attribute maximum, up to your augmented maximum**. *(Pg. 309 RAW)*

For *Improved Attribute*.

Comment: This could be modified to be more clear.  A longer summary with more explanation and less technical terms, followed by more formatting and less bold text in the rules quotes to support it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking the core rulebook and can't find **RAW** about this rule, but looking around NPCs and some examples I would say no, so you can buy with Karma up to your natural limit, and then you  add your Improved (Whatever) adept power up to your augmented maximum, the notation used for this stats are the same for cyberaugmented stats as:

Natural stat (augmented stat)

The **Brawling Adept** on page **117** follows this notation, as she has Improved Reflexes and a Reaction stat of **5(6)**.

The maximum augmented stat, core rulebook page 94:

> Keep in mind there are three restrictions when it
>   comes to purchasing gear. First, when purchasing augmentations
>   such as cyberware and bioware, each attribute
>   rating (Mental and Physical) can only receive an
>   augmentation bonus of up to +4.

This is the only reference I could find for **maximum augmentation** and as stated in **Improved Physical Attribute** page **309** core rulebook:

> This power allows you to increase a physical attribute
>   (Body, Agility, Reaction, and Strength). This augments
>   your attribute, so your Physical limit may also increase
>   with the new Attribute rating. This power allows you to
>   exceed your natural Attribute maximum, up to your augmented
>   maximum.

Other similar power, **Attribute Boost** have similar effects, but is cheaper and it must be activated with a Magic+Attribute test, but it also references **up to your augmented Attribute maximum.** (page 309 core rulebook too)

So I would state that there is **RAI** here, because if you have to purchase your attribute with Karma based on your total Attribute (Natural+Power) you would be paying more than an adept who grows with karma up to his natural maximum and then starts buying this kind of power.

The fact is that it is unclear how "permanent" the **Improved Physical Attribute** is, I would say that in some kind of "anti-magic" zone, the adept power would be negated, so it must rely on his natural stat and then the karma cost paid would have been unfair.

This also brings me this question: An adept could say that he "switches off" his power? This would be a tactic in order to leave no trace on astral plane of his presence, and if this is true the progression of the stat must be separated of the power progression, who must be bought purchasing Magic attribute and Initate powers (page **325** core rulebook)

So in the end:

- Adept natural stat --> Bought with karma up to his natural maximum
- Up to augmented maximum (Stat +4) --> Natural stat + Powers (+augmentations)

Comment: All of this to finally say: Stat/Skill progression always without any kind of boosting (Magic, Cyberware or Bioware)

Comment: Is really worth negatives?